# flip every other instance in array

Tags: modifiers

I have a road with street lamps going along next to it.

[image]

There is actually just one streetlamp, but I used a modifier to get it to get multiple instances of it to show up along the road.

[image]

The issues is that the lamps on the right side of the road are facing the wrong way. I tried adding a mirror modifier to it, ...

[image]

... and it worked, only now they are not staggered like I wanted them to be.

[image]

Is there a way to just flip every other instance of an array and still have it staggered? I'm using blender 2.8 if that's important.

EDIT: I know I can just duplicate the first one and get a second copy with it's own array, but I just want to know if it is possible to do it this way.

EDIT: I tried moving the mirror modifier under the first array modifier and it did this:

[image]

Also not what I wanted.